# How to remove data from a table view?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

I've set up my navigation bar with an add button that adds data to my table view. I've also added this line `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;` to create the edit button. Looking through the method I notice the `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method. So I made the modifications below, but my app freezes. What is the proper way to delete data from my table?

```
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source.
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];


        **[myArray removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        [self.tableView reloadData];**


    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to remove data from array first, and then notify table to remove corresponding rows. -reloadData call is unnecessary in this situation:

```
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source.
        [myArray removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];  
}
```